# How to convert an PImage image object to a java.io.File object?

Tags: java, file-io, processing

Is it possible to convert an image of a PImage object to a java.io.File object in Processing?

I could save the PImage first to the disk and load it into the File class but I don't think this is a good method. How can I convert from PImage to File directly?

Comment: Well, the two Objects are fundamentally different in java... The File object is a mere reference to a file or directory in the file system, while the PImage actually contains the pixel data of the image but not a location in the system where this image exists. So since one is reference and the other is actual content, a highly relevant question is what do you need the java.io.File for? As a side note, this is an answer: String imagePath = "Users/Carven/Desktop/lol.jpg"; PImage img = loadImage(imagePath); java.io.File f = new File(imagePath);

Comment: @PetrosKoutsolampros I get the feeling that he's generating the PImage on the fly ("save the PImage first to disk"), rather than loading an existing file.

Comment: kevinsa5 is right about what I said. Thanks.

Comment: Even so, read what I wrote. The File class does not hold any content so you can not "convert" the PImage to it. You can only save it somewhere and create a file out of it. I did ask you though to clarify what you need the File object for, since there might be something else you can do.